# Default Font Family for D3.js

Tags: d3.js, fonts, default, font-family

What is the default font family for D3.js?

I want my X and Y axis labels/tick mark labels and popups to all use the same font but am not sure what the default font is for axis labels.

Comment: I don't know much about D3, but from looking at the source code it doesn't seem to set its own font. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/search?q=font&type=Code

Comment: Does that mean the web browser sets the font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 does not have a default font. The default is whatever your browser/operating system sets.